# How to make a custom dependent dropdown menu using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm building a portfolio website for me and in this project I have a "Book Consultation" selection, where the clients can book a consultation with my team, and in this section I have a dependent dropdown menu which I have made using default HTML "option" tags and the design is not looking so professional. For this reason I want to implement those dropdown design using Custom "div" tags to make it more good looking. but I don't have the idea how to make this type of custom dropdown menu using div tags or how to implement the javascript logic for this.

I have also check the reference code's from codepen and chatgpt but not get any appropriate solution, I need any senior developer's help to implement this functionality.

I have made the exact design in HTML option tags, I just need the custom version of it to make it more beautiful.

```
<body>

<div class="consultation-section" id="book-consultation">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="consultation-heading">
                  <h2 class="heading-h text-white">Book A Consultation</h2>
                  <p class="heading-p text-white">Book A Consultation For Your Project & We'll Reach You Soon</p>
                  <hr class="heading-line-one">
               </div>

               <div class="consultation-form">
                  <form id="consult-form" class="consult-form">
                     <select class="consult-data" id="section-picker" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Project Type</option>
                        <option value="web-dev">Web Development</option>
                        <option value="grp-dsg">Graphic Designing</option>
                        <option value="dgt-mkt">Digital Marketing</option>
                     </select>

                        <select class="consult-data" id="web-section" required>
                           <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Sub-Project Type</option>
                           <option value="">► Static Website Development</option>
                           <option value="">► Dynamic Website Development</option>
                           <option value="">► CMS Website Development</option>
                        </select>

                        <select class="consult-data" id="graphic-section" required>
                           <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Sub-Project Type</option>
                           <option value="">► Banner Designing</option>
                           <option value="">► Logo Designing</option>
                           <option value="">► Mockup Designing</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="consult-data" id="marketing-section" required>
                           <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Sub-Project Type</option>
                           <option value="">► One-Page SEO</option>
                           <option value="">► Off-Page SEO</option>
                           <option value="">► Brand Promotion</option>
                        </select>

                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
         
 <style>
 
 .consultation-section {
    background-color: #323757;
    height: 100%;
}

.consultation-section .container {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.consultation-heading {
    padding-top: 2.3rem;
}

.heading-h, .heading-p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.consultation-form {
    margin-top: 3.1rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.consultation-form input:focus, 
.consultation-form select:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.consultation-form input {
    color: #313131;
}

.consultation-form input, 
.consultation-form select, 
.consultation-form select option {
    /* font-weight: 550; */
}

.consultation-form select option {
    line-height: 60px;
}

.consultation-form form *::placeholder {
    color: #323757;
    opacity: 1;
}

.consult-data {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #323757;
    /* font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 450; */
    box-shadow: inherit;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: #fff solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 30px
}

input.sub1 {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px
}

.sub2 {
    zoom: 1.2;
    color: #fff;
}

.consultation-form label span {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#graphic-section, 
#marketing-section, 
#web-section {
    display: none
}

.consult-btn {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 550;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #e8576f;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    height: 47px;
    line-height: 47px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: ease-in all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: ease-in all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: ease-in all 0.5s;
    transition: ease-in all 0.5s;
}

.consult-btn:hover {
    color: #e8576f;
    background-color: #fff;
}
 
 </style>
         

<script>

document.getElementById('section-picker').addEventListener('change', function() {

  let WebDev = document.getElementById("web-section");
  let GrpDsg = document.getElementById("graphic-section");
  let DgtMkt = document.getElementById("marketing-section");

  (this.value == "web-dev") ? WebDev.style.display = "block" : WebDev.style.display = "none";
  (this.value == "grp-dsg") ? GrpDsg.style.display = "block" : GrpDsg.style.display = "none";
  (this.value == "dgt-mkt") ? DgtMkt.style.display = "block" : DgtMkt.style.display = "none";

});

</script>

</body>
```